# Excel 2007 stays open when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-interop

I know this has been talked about a lot but I can't find a solution which would solve my  specific problem.

I've written code to copy data from a `.csv` file to a `.xlsb` file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. My problem is that when I use a machine that has Excel 2007 installed on it the Excel process remains open.

I've tested the same code with Excel 2003 and 2010 and everything works fine.

Most solutions to similar problems talk about a reference being left behind so I cut down most of the code until I was left with this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application oApp = null;
        Excel.Workbooks oWBs = null;
        Excel.Workbook oWB = null;

        try
        {
            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            oApp = new Excel.Application();

            // Open existing workbook
            oWBs = oApp.Workbooks;
            oWB = oWBs.Open(xlsbFile);

            // Save the workbook
            oWB.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            String errorMessage;
            errorMessage = "Error: ";
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            oWB.Close(false);
            while (Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWB) > 0) { };
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            oWB = null;

            oWBs.Close();
            while (Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWBs) > 0) { };
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            oWBs = null;

            oApp.Quit();
            while (Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp) > 0) { };
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            oApp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be most appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can give a try to OpenXml SDK. It's a completely different approach (and code) but maybe it's worth the effort

Comment: @DavideLettieri great advice[/sarcasm] specially that the OP has already done all the work and just simply can't properly close the app instance...

Comment: have you tried to move the `oWB = null` before `GC.Collect()`? also try `oWB.Saved = true;` before you Save

Comment: @mehow since nobody offers a solution... anyway i really think that openxml it's a good choice and a valid alternative to interop. Moreover openxml it's the ONLY choice if you are working server side as stated for example in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses. Since the whole thing took too much time the client went and upgraded Microsoft Office to 2013 and it works as is. Just to keep track for future reference: the above code works for EXCEL 2003, 2010 and 2013. I'll have to try OpenXML on a future project.